# How to pass multiple key-value pairs as query parameter in Python Django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am building a key-value store REST API that will store data in a key value pair. Suppose I want to create an endpoint where I can make a GET request to `values/` to get one or more values by passing one or more keys just like this:

```
/values?keys=key1,key2,key3
```

I want to know what should I do in `urls.py` if I want to do this variable length query.

This is my model:

```
class Data(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    value = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}:{}'.format(self.key, self.value)
```

Comment: you dont do anything in urls for query strings .... you just access `request.GET`

Comment: thanks, easy things are sometimes harder to understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need do anything in your `url.py`. You just need get your query param (in your case it is keys) in your `view.py` and you can do this like below:

```
def your_view(request):
    keys = request.query_params.get('keys')
```

Comment: Thanks, it works just fine. By the way, I used request.GET.getlist()